# Automatically adding Rows in a chart based on Pivot Tables

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a question regarding the usage of two pivot tables and one regular table.

For my pivot tables they update based on a column from another sheet. For example, if that column has three departments: Dept A, B and C then the pivot table rows are Dept A, Dept B, Dept C with respective information in each of the columns. From this pivot table I have a regular table that the data goes into that is then turned into a PDF for review (easier format to understand). The regular table is set up the same way with the rows being the same as the pivot: Dept A, B and C.

My Issue: If, say, a Dept D was added to the sheet the pivot table pulls from. The pivot table can be refreshed to contain now: Dept A, B, C and D. But my table does not change, it only has Dept A, B and C. How do I get my table to contain the same Dept's as the pivot table without manually adding a row and filling in the formulas??

```
![enter image description here][1]
![enter image description here][2]
![enter image description here][3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pivot table is recognizing the now resized range, you can either adjust the data source every time you want to refresh or do the following:

1. Highlight your source dataset
2. `CTRL` + `T` - This will give you a name tabled format, use the name references to do you pivot table. To find the name, click the table and under the new tab in the ribbon you'll see the table name in the leftmost side, you can change it from there as well.
3. Refresh

The code in VBA would be `Thisworkbook.RefreshAll` if you want a code for it

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am still confused. To clarify, if I have a pivot table that shows row Dept A and row Dept B with respective metrics in the columns and I add Dept C. Which is then recognized by the pivot table thus added under Dept B. However, the regular table that contains Dept A and B does not recognize Dept C. My question is... How do you get Dept C to show up in a regular table that was originally only showing Dept A and B automatically when the pivot table is updated? Thank you!

Comment: You're asking if you add Dept D to your table, it IS reflected by your pivot table, but not your original table that it was input into? I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you're asking, is there a 3rd table? Can you please clarify how these are all connected?

Comment: I have two data sets (sheet1 and sheet2). I have two pivot tables (Pivot1 and Pivot2). Both pivot tables filter from their respective datasheet. I have a regular table I made to put data in from specific columns in each pivot table. The Pivot Rows are by Dept. The regular Table Rows are by dept. My question is... My pivot tables update to show additional rows when a new Dept is entered but my regular table has to manually be updated. Is there a way to have my regular table update and add a new row with the respective Dept when the PivotTables are updated and show a new row?